# get api response data out of the scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have used Async Storage in my React native app. so i have set the data by set AsyncStorage.setItem("@Token", jsonValue). and i have create another function for get data so, i unable to get my response out the scope of promise

Code:

```
storeData = async (value) => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@Token", jsonValue);
    } catch (e) {
      // saving error
    }
  };

  getData =   () => {
    const getTodos =  AsyncStorage.getItem("@Token");
getTodos.the((res)=>{

return res;
})
    if(res!==null){

        return true;
    }
else{


    return false
}
   


}
```

Answer (score 1):

A value returned from a Promise is only accessible from within its `.then()` callback. This means that `res` is only available inside `getTodos.then((res) => { ... })`.

```js
storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("@Token", jsonValue);
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
};

getData = () => {
  const getTodos = AsyncStorage.getItem("@Token");
  getTodos.then((res) => {
    if (res !== null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want `getData` to return the item from the storage.

Try something like this

```
getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@Token");
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getData =   () => {
try {
    const getTodos =  AsyncStorage.getItem("@Token");
    if (getTodos !== null) {
      console.log(getTodos);
    return true;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
   return false;
  }
}
}
```